# What are the different conceptualizations/definitions for what a "the state of matter" is?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, solid-state-physics, terminology, plasma-physics, states-of-matter

**My understanding:**

So, the classic four states of matter are *solid, liquid, gaseous* and *plasma*. My understanding is that they differ along the same axis; the cohesion of their constituent parts. This cohesion is delineated into four stages, these stages being distinguished by the bulk mass' behaviour in a "non-constraining environment", as I call it. A non-constraining environment is a space that is sufficiently large for max dispersion, that also doesn't put the bulk mass under any external stress.

In a solid, the constituent particles are quite stuck; they are close enough to each other that they can have interatomic bonding, which is strong enough to keep them quite still. Still enough to not flow out and cover an area. So, in a non-constraining environment, the bulk mass just stands still.

In a liquid, the particles are so far away that only intermolecular forces are at play. This allows the bulk mass to flow out and disperse across as much of the underlying surface as it can, unlike a solid mass which just sits still. The liquid particles still generally stick together, though since the liquid's bulk mass has a greater capacity to move, it will endure more kinetic stress, and since the bonds are weaker, it will thus tend to break apart. This causes the bulk mass to often separate into smaller and smaller parts given that it's travelling across a surface/space that is sufficiently large. However, these parts always stay multi-molecular, given no extraordinary stress (which is, by definition, not found in a non-constraining environment).

For the gaseous state however, the constintuent particles don't even stick together, since the intermolecular forces are so weak. Thus, a gas is made up of lone particles travelling around.

In the plasma state, even the particles split apart, into their ionic and/or sub-atomic components.

So, the four stages are simple: original bulk mass stays whole (solid), bulk mass split into smaller masses (liquid), smaller masses split into the constintuent particles (gas), constituent particles split into their smaller components.

---

**Going beyond the classics:**

This explanation doesn't seem to reach further than those classic ones however. If one includes the Bose-Einstein Condensate, it rather seems that the only distinction that stays consistent is the degree of freedom of movement that the particles have, which is none in the Bose-Einstein Condensate, and boundless in the gaseous state. In the plasma state however, I am not sure if the freedom of movement is boundless, and it is, doesn't that put it on the same spot along the axis as a gas, meaning they're the same state? Perhaps the answer to this is that the states of matter are separated along multiple axes?

Another problem with this way of distinguishing the states is that it, as far as I can tell, introduces a completely arbitrary choice as to exactly what points of freedom are sufficient to say the mass has entered a different state. The aforementioned delineation has AFAIK an objective way to tell between the states, whereas the other requires a quantification of movement freedom, and then a choice of what quantities "start" the next state.

---

**The question:**

With all of these fairly common claims of "a new state of matter", and their rebuttals, I wonder what the competeing viewpoints/understandings that give rise to these debates are. What are the definitions/conceptualizations regarding the axis or axes that separate the states of matter?

Comment: Usually *state of matter* means a [thermodynamic phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(matter)). See also [critical phenomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_phenomena. In the latter context one would say that different phases differ by absence/presence of some symmetry/order parameter.